# How do I generate PDF of HTML in a custom module?

Tags: files

I want to generate PDF in my custom module. Using print module we can print node. But I have made html in my custom module and that I wanted to make pdf and save it in files.

I have tried custom **dompfg** library but its working. 
i wanted to do something like this:

```
$html = "<h1>Header</h1><P>Pdf generated.</p>";

include ("mpdf.php"); /// This will be something to include for mpdf 
$mpdf=new mPDF('win-1252','A4','','',20,15,48,25,10,10); 
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output('../default/files/users/filename.pdf','F'); 
exit;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is quite a bit more involved in integrating Drupal with the mPDF library than the code snippet you show.

As often with Drupal, there is a module for that. It is named [PDF using mPDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/pdf_using_mpdf), and this is what it will do:

> This module is used for Conversion of HTML pages to PDF documents using mPDF PHP Library. It allows you to generate a pdf document of any node.

Make sure you follow the instructions in the README.txt files carefully. You need to place the mPDF library in the right directory, and install the [Libraries API](http://drupal.org/project/libraries), for it to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate PDF Using Html using dompdf

In my case I need to create a pdf from a custom menu callback.
So to achieve this

Step 1 : Download [dompdf](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf-info/) library

Step 2 : Place the library in sites/all/libraries/dompdf

Step3 : Create a function like the following for download pdf for your custom html

```
<?php

require_once("sites/all/libraries/dompdf/autoload.inc.php");
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

function generate_custom_pdf(){

  $html = '<put your html content here>'; // you may add your content here

  $dompdf = new Dompdf();
  $dompdf->load_html($html);
  $dompdf->render();
  // This does not save the pdf field and instead it opens a dialog box asking whether you have to save the pdf or not
  $dompdf->stream("ckl-sample.pdf");
  drupal_exit();
}

?>
```